# How to use external python script in django views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

If suppose I have a file full of functions in python naming **basics.py** which **does not have a class** inside it.
and there's **no   __init__()** function too.
Now if I want to access the functions of **basics.py** inside the **views.py** .
How can I do that?

Comment: use an import statement in views.py `import basics`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html You should read more about Python.

Comment: Not having a class is *usual*. There is absolutely no need for one if you're not keeping state. And `__init__()` methods are only used within classes anyway.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: If you can share your project structure, that would help a lot.

Comment: I get error saying unresolved reference using `import basics` and `from basics import *`

Comment: @Grimmy I am using Python 3
```-project   
-->app   
---->views   
---->basics   
----> all the remaining files   
-->project and all files inside   
-->manage.py   
```

Comment: @ShreyanshLodha I don't understand the file hierarchy you are explaining here so I made some assumptions in my answer. If you have the ``tree`` command you can generate a nice looking file hierarchy you can paste in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake because python 3 have stricter rules when it comes to relative imports.

I assume you have a structure like this.

```
myapp
├── basics.py
└── views.py
```

.. where `myapp` is in the root of your project.

Let's assume `basics.py` looks like this.

```
def do_stuff():
    pass
```

The ways you can import things from basic would then be (`views.py`)

```
from myapp import basics
from myapp.basics import do_stuff
from . import basics
from .basics import do_stuff

# View code ...
```

I assumed here that `basics.py` and `views.py` are located in the same package (`app`).

When you run a python project your current directory is added to the python path. You will either have to import all the way from the root of your project or use `.` to import from the local package/directory.

Also notice in the example that you can import the entire module or just single functions/objects. When importing the entire `basics` module you access it using `basics.do_stuff()` in the view.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
import basics
```

than use all the functions you want :)

Comment: This assumes the person is using a relative import in python 2 or the module is in the root of the python path.

Comment: it gives me an error saying unresolved reference 'basics'